# Outlook rule issue

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, rules

I have created a rule in Outlook for any email where the subject contains "17-4" to move to folder 17-4. The problem I'm facing is that any email where 17-4 appears in the subject line, it gets moved to this folder. I know that's the point, but for example an email with 17-432 in the subject line is also getting moved there too.

I have tried to use quotes, in hope that it would only allow 17-4 specifically, to no avail.

I think there's an easy solution here, I just can't find it.

Comment: You could try putting a space after "17-4", iow "17-4 ".